# Listening to the item move event with outlook add-in

Tags: visual-studio, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I want to do some functionality when user moves a  mail item (from a folder to another folder).  So I want to capture the mail item move event with the outlook add-in.
I think this should be possible with following event handlers,

```
MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler
ItemsEvents_ItemRemoveEventHandler
```

I tried with both of the above event handles. But they didn’t work for me. Could someone provide an example. Here is the code for `MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler`.

```
    Outlook.Folder fldr;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        fldr = (Outlook.Folder)Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
        fldr.BeforeItemMove += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
             MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler
             (Folder_BeforeItemMove); 
    }

    private void Folder_BeforeItemMove(object anItem, MAPIFolder aMoveToFolder, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (anItem as Outlook.MailItem);
        //Do other stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The object that raises the events (fldr) must be declared on the class level instead of local to avoid being released by the Garbage Collector.

Comment: Ok I moved but still not working. I will change the code segment in the questions to reflect this change.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? Older versions of Outlook have problems with that event. Do you see the even fire in OutlookSpy (click Folder button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the Events tab, look at the log at the bottom of the page, move some message)?

Comment: I am using outlook 2010.

Comment: I am using outlook 2010. In OutlookSpy event tab I can see "BeforeFolderMove" and "BeforeItemMove" events selected with check boxes. 
And in the log when I move a mail from inbox to a folder I can see log entry "BeforeItemMove (IDispatch, IDispatch, false)"

But it is not hitting the debug point inside Folder_BeforeItemMove() in VisualStudio IDE. Based on that I am assuming this as not working.

Comment: Hi, I think I found the issue here. When initializing folder I used OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks but it should be OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox. And inbox to other folder movements are working now. But what about the movements withing the sub-folders inside inbox, how can I listen to those movements?

Comment: You would need to dynamically set up event handlers on those folders as well. You can use a list (List<MAPIFolder>) to keep these folders referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your support, it is working. I want to use the same plugin on 2013 as well. Do you see any issues on it?

Comment: Dmitry, Do you have an idea of a possible way of extending (or adding to a windows form) outlook's folder move dialog box? Related to the question I asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230021/display-outlook-folder-tree-in-a-form-outlook-add-in-project?noredirect=1#comment39300676_25230021

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar requirement for iterating through MailFolders.

So please try as below:

Outlook.MAPIFolder mapifldr;
Outlook.Folder fldr;

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   mapifldr=Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
    fldr = (Outlook.Folder) Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetFolderFromID(mapifldr.EntryID);
    fldr.BeforeItemMove += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
         MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler
         (Folder_BeforeItemMove); 
}
```

This is a very old post but hope it saves time for others.