# Display outlook folder tree in a form (outlook add-in project)

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, windows-forms-designer

I want to customize the mail moving functionality of outlook. So to do that I am creating a outlook plugin and when user want to move a mail, I will show a windows form via that add-in.
In that windows form I want to display the current folder tree of outlook as in the following image (this image is from mail move functionality : mail --> right mouse click --> move -> to other folder).

Is there a way that I can get similar tree by extending already having outlook UI component

[image]?

I am using outlook 2010.

Regards.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. I've done something similar in the past and I build the UI using the outlook application and MAPIFolder objects. As it can be quite slow, I made sure the folders were loaded on demand, well, only when expanded.

Comment: Actually I was able to get MAPIFolder objects to a list and I am not experiencing slowness. What I am worry about making the UI. If I can use the mentioned dialog box in my windows form or if I can extend it that will be great.

Comment: I don't understand your issue with the UI is? If your question is, is there such a dialog already available, then I think the answer is No and you'll have to build it yourself, but that should be no big deal. Simple treeview will do the trick.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks. Yea I was asking for an available dialog box. I am interested on it as it look and feel very good in user perspective (as it is having unique icons and names for folder items). Yes I will go for make one by iterating folders.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Customize the built-in Outlook Select Names dialog (or any other)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21288/Customize-the-built-in-Outlook-Select-Names-dialog)

It might be what you are looking for.